# Display the name of the current open file in a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, openfiledialog

I am creating a basic text editing piece of software in C# using Visual Studio 2012.

I would like to display the name of the open file in a label.

Currently, my `OpenFileDialog` code consists of:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.ShowDialog();
try
{
    richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = ofd.FileName;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text);
    richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();

    richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.LoadFile(ofd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
catch { }
}
```

Let's say for example, I open Document.rtf using this software. How can I display that "Document.rtf" or any other open file title in a label (named `filename1`)?

Comment: Why do you set the text to the file's name and then overwrite it with its contents...and then load it? Don't you want to display the file's name in a **separate** label?

Comment: why can't you capture of the `FileName` once you've selected the file.. there is a property called `FileName` you know..

Comment: Why are you ignoring exceptions? Remove that try/catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Path.GetFileName Method`

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string result = Path.GetFileName(fileName); 
Console.WriteLine(result); // outputs  myfile.ext
```

- [Path.GetFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

**UPDATE 1**

```
string fileName = ofd.FileName;
richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.LoadFile(fileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
label1.Text = Path.GetFileName(fileName); //  here's your label
```

Comment: I think he is after the file name from the dialog?

Comment: I'm trying to display the name of the current open file on a label.

Comment: @CRice then he can pass `ofd.FileName` into the variable `string fileName = ofd.FileName;` or directly use `ofd.FileName`

Comment: Sorted now. J W's update gave the answer (switching the label and the richtextbox line around).

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the user actually selects a file in the `OpenFileDialog`. Then set the text:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
// make sure user selects a file
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    try{
        // load contents
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.LoadFile(ofd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText); 
        // update label with file name
        filename1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName);
    }catch{
        // handle exception as you wish
    }
}
```

Comment: Should have probably mentioned that I'm new to programming (studying it at college), so forgive me if I say something stupid.

Comment: No problem. Just make sure to check that the user did accept the file dialog or you'll have an exception thrown for trying to access the file's name when it wasn't selected!

Comment: Got my catch in place. Just tested it out and all is good. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Even with the try/catch. Check if the user clicked OK or not...you'll avoid running unnecessary code and throwing exceptions, even it you catch them.